# How can you select common elements from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables t1 to t37. Each have a primary key ID. But each table does not have the same number of IDs. I would like to compare IDs across tables and get ones which have at least one match in another table. I have already created a query which gives me the result for the following example. But is there a way to do this when I have a large number of tables?

Example: If `A (1,2,3,4,5,6)`, `B (1,7,8)`, `C (6,7,8)` then I should get `(1,6,7,8)`.

Query example

Schema (PostgreSQL v12)

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (6);

CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO test1 (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test1 (id) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO test1 (id) VALUES (8);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO test2 (id) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO test2 (id) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO test2 (id) VALUES (8);
```

---

Query #1

```
select *
from test

intersect

select *
from test1

union

select *
from test

intersect

select *
from test2

union

select *
from test1

intersect

select *
from test2;
```

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 1   |
| 8   |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `union all` all of the ids together and then group the id:

```
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT id FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id FROM test1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id FROM test2
) sub
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id)>1;
```